# $\sigma$-algebras generated by open and closed sets from $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equal proof

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

Given the following two sets:

1) $\mathcal{E_1} := \{A \subset \mathbb{R}^n: A  \text{ is open} \}$

2) $\mathcal{E_2} := \{A \subset \mathbb{R}^n: A \text{ is closed}  \}$

I have a proof here that says that $\sigma$-algebras generated by those sets are in fact equal. The proof starts off trivially:

Let $A \in \mathcal{E_1}$, then $A^c \in \mathcal{E_2}$ and this implies: $(A^c)^c=A \in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$, because of the closure under complements property of $\sigma$-algebras. It then follows that: $\mathcal{E_1} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$. Up to now all is clear for me. Now the next step I do not follow.

The author says "According to Remark 1.17": $\sigma(\mathcal{E_1}) \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$. I do not see how from using the below properties from Remark 1.17, we can arrive at the above result (below is the remark):

[image]

I guess this direction is easy, because $\mathcal{E_1} \subset \mathcal{E_2}$. But the other direction (he says the same argument applies, thus I am interested to understand his argument), i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{E_2}) \subset(\mathcal{E_1})$, I would actually need to understand his argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal E_1\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal E_2)$ then according to 1.17 (ii): $$\sigma(\mathcal E_1)\subseteq \sigma(\sigma(\mathcal E_2))\tag1$$

$\sigma(\mathcal E_2)$ is by definition a $\sigma$-algebra so according to 1.17 (iii): $$\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal E_2))=\sigma(\mathcal E_2)\tag2$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ together give: $$\sigma(\mathcal E_1)\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal E_2)$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $\mathcal{E_1} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$. By Remark (ii) we derive

$\sigma(\mathcal{E_1}) \subset \sigma (\sigma(\mathcal{E_2}))$. But $\sigma (\sigma(\mathcal{E_2}))=\sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$.